Exporting Highchart using JS PDF but its not supporting for Other Language Text translation
Exporting Highchart using JS PDF. its working for English Language and when we change other language it shows invalid character in JS PDF.
pdf.svg(svgImage, {
                    x: chartOffset.x,
                    y: chartOffset.y,
                    width: chartWidth,
                    height: chartHeight,
                }).then(() => {
                    pdf.save(fileName);
                    
                });

https://jsfiddle.net/ranjithkumarsv/La89x4n7/4/
Other language translation also need to support in JS PDF.
Note: We can see translated text inside svgImage.
